# fullpage.js - Get the active Section Index number

Tags: fullpage.js

The is pretty straightforward. I'm trying to find a way to get the active section Index number. I want the number to change when you scroll to a different section.

What I want to achieve:
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT5PY.jpg)

Comment: Unclear on what is being asked.Kindly rephrase to attract help.

Comment: Thanks Keshav, I will try to be more clear. I am trying to get the index number of a section when it has the class of .active. At the moment, I am able to get the total number of sections using .lenght but I'm not able to get the section number that has the active class.

Comment: Here's a gif of what I want to achieve: https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/3d230M020C2h0H1o443K/Screen%20recording%202018-02-28%20at%2001.08.03%20AM.gif

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [fullPage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) or [state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs).

Notice you have the `slideIndex` on the callbacks:

```
afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
    //do whatever here
    $(body).append(slideIndex);
},
```

Because the `afterSlideLoad` callback won't get fired on section change, you'll need to also make use of the `afterLoad` callback and get the slide number by using the state classes added by fullPage.js:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    var slideNumber = $('.fp-section.active').find('.fp-slide.active').index() + 1
 //do whatever here
    $(body).append(slideNumber);
}
```