# Display current section number using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I have seen this question asked here [BEFORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022826/fullpage-js-get-the-active-section-index-number)  and the answer helped... kind of.

I am using fullPage.js, I have a side bar and I have a div inside this sidebar which will display a number depending on which slide is active

I have a div

```
<div id="num" class="slideNumber"></div>
```

and I have this snippit

```
var slideNumber = $('.fp-section.active').find('.fp-slide.active').index() + 1;
 //do whatever here
    $('#num').text(slideNumber);
```

The number inside the div is displaying 0, then on scroll it refreshes that div to say 0 again each time a section is passed. I want this to instead change the number depending on which section its on.

Edit: I fixed it. Solution below:

```
 var slideNumber = $('.fp-section.active').index() + 1;
 //This will change the input of NUM to current section number
 $('#num').html(slideNumber);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var slideNumber = $('.fp-section.active').index() + 1;
 //This will change the input of NUM to current section number
 $('#num').html(slideNumber);
```

I removed

```
.find('.fp-slide.active')
```

and replaced

```
$('#num').text(slideNumber);
```

with

```
$('#num').html(slideNumber);
```

and it started outputting correctly inside the #num div